# <code> tag doesn't text highlight

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, syntax-highlighting, code-block

I noticed the other day that [two nearly identical answers to a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2888725/multiple-depends-in-ant-task) were slightly different.

The first one (the accepted answer) uses four spaces. The second answer (highest non-accepted answer, at time of this writing) uses `<code>` tags. I'm pretty sure this is why it doesn't highlight.

It seems to me that the two should use the same engine for rendering, but it doesn't appear to be that way.

Comment: Related: [How do I format my code blocks?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, they don't use the same engine. For one, the markdown syntax adds a `<pre class="...">` tag *around* the `<code>` tags with language highlighting metadata.

Markdown *happens* to support inline HTML for 'manual' formatting, but once you move to such manual formatting, you also loose the possibility to attach richer metadata such as the language highlighter to use.

If you *must* use `<code>` add a `<pre>` tag around it (no class or style information, that'll cause it to be filtered out) and optionally add a highlight hint:

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

<pre><code>&lt;some>
    &lt;bogus>&lt;xml />&lt;/bogus>
&lt;/some>
</code></pre>
```

becomes:

```xml
<some>
    <bogus><xml /></bogus>
</some>
```

but you have to do all the escaping by hand. :-)

Comment: So `<code>` isn't part of Markdown, it's actually part of html?

Comment: @corsiKa: exactly. It's a HTML 5 element.

Comment: Well then, I'd say it's hardly a bug... thanks!

Comment: @corsiKa: nope, this is `status-bydesign`.

Comment: `<pre><code>` [works just fine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/167176#167176).

Comment: @Arjan: Ah, it's the class and style attributes that cause it to be filtered out.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. Plain `<pre><code>` is also enhanced by the SE JavaScript, which then makes Prettify highlight it. Still then, Markdown 4-spaces is so much easier, if only as one does not have to encode any `<` and `>` characters.

Comment: ...and the highlight hint is not needed if the question is tagged with some language ;-)

Comment: @Arjan: I mean that if you add in `<pre class="...">` the `pre` tag is removed again. I was updating my answer with the same info already. :)

Comment: @Arjan: Ah, added a 'optionally' in there.

Comment: Hmm that sure does seem like a lot of work. I guess it was just by a user who didn't know about Markdown. Thanks for the thorough analysis!

Answer (score 1):

The highlighting doesn't work because it's specified in the surround `<pre>` tag, not the `<code>` tag:

```
<pre class="lang-xml prettyprint" style="">
    <code>
```

Using `<pre><code>` works just fine too:

```html
Look ma, <em style="xyz">highlighting</em>!
```

Using `<code>` alone is bad practice. If you *must* use HTML instead of Markdown, you should use `<pre><code>`, which is what indentation by four spaces generates.

Comment: `prettyprinted` is added by Prettify.

Comment: I just ninja-edited the answer to add `<pre>` tags. It prettifies.

Comment: (I meant the "prettyprinted" CSS class; but I edited it out.)